# login with google stopped working cookiepolicy is a required field

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-openid

I'm using google sign in js in my web application, I was using these 3 statements in meta data

```
    <meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="1111111111111111111.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" />
    <meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
```

suddenly It stopped working and give me this error `cookiepolicy is a required field`

The idea that the site was working without problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that google no more recognize cookiepolicy in meta data. you must put it in the params of the `gapi.auth.signIn`

```
    var additionalParams = {
            'callback': signinCallback,
            'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin'
        };

    gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams);
```